# Reference DTM row by document number and save to vector/matrix

Tags: r, text-mining

How do I reference a particular row in a DTM by document number? In addition, how do I save this row as a vector/matrix?.

Please see output of DTM below, when calling `inspect(test)`

```
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 247, terms: 59599)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 108783/14612170
Sparsity           : 99%
Maximal term length: 51
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
      Terms
Docs   can get just know like one peopl thing 
  2242  13  16   15    4   16  12    42    17    
  2289  16   3    7    7   22  10    33     8     
  2299  14  12    2   11   16  22    12    10     
  2307  40  17   40   21   40  25    74    30    
  2339  27  20   41   11   39  22    77    18    
  2348  12   6    8   20   17   6    11    13    
  2357   9  10   17   32   47  12    14     8    
  2359  34  18   27    6   46  23    28    28    
  2382   9  11   10    6   19   8    12     4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the fact that a document term matrix has a dimnames.

`dtm[dtm$dimnames$Docs == 2289, ]` will return only the data in the row where documentid equals 2289. To put this in a matrix, just call `as.matrix`.

`as.matrix(dtm[dtm$dimnames$Docs == 2289, ])` will be a 1 row matrix